# meteor callback heaven calling a callback after another callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, callback

I have set up 3 functions where the need to run after each other

I have set up my callback correctly and able to invoke functionTwo after functionOne like this...

```
functionOne(functionTwo) // this is fine
```

How do invoke functionThree after functionTwo?

I tried `functionOne(functionTwo(functionThree))` but this is wrong

My code

```
   var functionOneAsync = function(callback) {
     request.post('http://www.goodreads.com/oauth/access_token', {
     oauth: {consumer_key: 'somekey',
            consumer_secret: 'somesecretkey',
            token: oauthToken,
            token_secret: oauthTokenSecret}
  },
  function (error, response, body){
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      var perm_data = querystring.parse(body)
      var accessToken = perm_data.oauth_token
      var tokenSecret = perm_data.oauth_token_secret
      console.log('exch done')
      return callback(null, accessToken, tokenSecret)
    }
    else {
      callback(error)
    }
  })
}
var functionOneAsyncSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(functionOneAsync);

var functionTwoAsync = function(error, accessToken, tokenSecret, callback) {
  request.get('https://www.goodreads.com/api/auth_user', {
    oauth: {consumer_key:'somekey',
            consumer_secret:'somesecretkey',
            token: accessToken,
            token_secret: tokenSecret
            }
  },
  function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      var options = {
        object: true,
        reversible: false,
        coerce: true,
        sanitize: true,
        trim: true,
        arrayNotation: false
      }
      var bodyToJson = parser.toJson(body, options)
      var goodreadsUserId = bodyToJson.GoodreadsResponse.user.id
      console.log('user id done' + goodreadsUserId)
      return callback(null, accessToken, tokenSecret, goodreadsUserId)
      }
    else {
      return callback(error)
    }
  })
}
var functionTwo = Meteor.wrapAsync(functionTwoAsync);



 var functionThreeAsync = function(error, accessToken, tokenSecret, goodreadsUserId) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('error in storing')
    console.log(error)
  }
  else {
    Meteor.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()}, {$set: {'profile.goodreads.accessToken': accessToken, 'profile.goodreads.tokenSecret': tokenSecret, 'profile.goodreads.userID': goodreadsUserId}});
    console.log('reached storing in user collection')
  }
}
var functionThree = Meteor.wrapAsync(functionThreeAsync);
```

Comment: Show the code for functionTwo

Comment: @Yuri I have pasted, please see above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor gives great solution for callback hell.

If you already wrapped functions with Meteor.wrapAsync, then you should be able to run them like this (pseudo code):

```
try {
 var resultOne = functionOne();
 var resultTwo = functionTwo(resultOne.accessToken, resultOne.tokenSecret, ...)
 var resultThree = functionThree(resultOne.accessToken, resultOne.tokenSecret, ...)
} catch ( e ) {
   console.error('functionOne or functionTwo or functionThree thrown error = ', e);
}
```

If you want to run them as above, you need implement your functions in the way like this:

```
var functionTwoAsync = function(accessToken, tokenSecret, callback) {
  request.get('https://www.goodreads.com/api/auth_user', {
    oauth: {...}
  },
  function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

      // IMPORTANT !!!
      return callback(
            null, 
            { 
              accessToken : accessToken,
              tokenSecret : tokenSecret,
              goodreadsUserId : goodreadsUserId
            }
      )
    } else {
      return callback(error)
    }
  })
}
var functionTwo = Meteor.wrapAsync(functionTwoAsync);
```

Comment: is it necessary to pass the values all in one object to the next function? Or can I keep it simple as pass multiple values as I have done already? I will try your method and let you know how I get on. Thank you for your input

Comment: if you want to return multiple variables from previous function then it is necessary.

Comment: Does this mean my function three simply takes an error and result parameter. the result parameter containing the object of the three fields accessToken, tokenSecret and goodreadsUserId?

Comment: Take a closer look at implementation of functionTwoAsync and see what is passed to callback.

Comment: Implement functionOneAsync and functionThreeAsync  in analogous way I wrote functionTwoAsync

Comment: I am getting an error on the line in functionTwoAsync on the line ... else {
      return callback(error)
    }    "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: That means callback wasn't passed.

Comment: I will create example, give me few minutes

Comment: Check this out :  https://github.com/parhelium/laboratory/commit/6cf54f03ac9d18087107920111c76097133b1d9e

Comment: If add Meteor.user.update(....) in fucntionTwo and remove the callback feature within functionTwo, I get the error, "Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment."

Comment: Please start analyzing my example, try to run it locally and understand how it works. Once you do that it will be easy for you to modify code for your needs. Your questions are going out of the scope of this question.

Comment: I will do, can you explain what the numbers do in the paramters e.g. var resultOne = one( 1,2,3,4 )

Comment: This is only example, which shows that you are able to pass any number of arguments to function wrapped with Meteor.wrapAsync.

Comment: I used the method of declaring a variable name for each function that has been given a name. (Just like your example). This allows me to put the result, which is the variable name into the next function. I realised using future to wait before returning worked without a glitch for each function.
Maybe I dont fully understand exactly what wrapAsync does. I found future easier to follow and construct my code.

Comment: Just to confirm, although the code behaves 'synchronous style after the way the variables are declared onto each function, is it non-blocking between multiple users?